# Using CASE however surely there is a more succinct way to write this

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a more succinct way to write this code? FYI the values I’ve listed are all different, despite what is currently shown.
There are also more 'ES' values, that have CP = C, S2, P, F. (I did try to submit the whole code however this website told me it was too much code...)

```
CASE WHEN ES = 'W' AND CP = 'S' THEN -.75

                    ELSE ES = 'W' AND CP = 'C' THEN -.06

                    ELSE ES = 'W' AND CP = 'S2' THEN -.5

                    ELSE ES = 'W' AND CP = 'P' THEN -.3

                    ELSE ES = 'W' AND CP = 'F' THEN -.1

                   

      

                    ELSE ES = 'S' AND CP = 'S' THEN -.75

                    ELSE ES = 'S' AND CP = 'C' THEN -.08

                    ELSE ES = 'S' AND CP = 'S2' THEN -.8

                    ELSE ES = 'S' AND CP = 'P' THEN -.2

                    ELSE ES = 'S' AND CP = 'F' THEN -.4

                    

End
```

Comment: I would suggest to put these in a translation table that you can join on ES and CP and get back the value you need

Comment: You've effectively written out another table in a very laborious fashion, with columns `ES`, `CP` and whatever your `THEN` values represent. It would be more effective to store this data in a table (whether that's a permanent part of the DB or just part of this script/procedure only you can say) and then join to it.

Comment: Thanks for the responses - I can't store it on the database unfortunately which forces me to go down this route of using CASE to create what i am wanting. I would have thought the way i've written this using CASE was long and tedious, and just assumed that surely there was a better way to write this

Comment: Where do you have this case expression? SELECT clause, or ON/WHERE clause. or ORDER BY etc?

Comment: Use a CTE to establish the "table" temporarily and then join with the CTE. More difficult to expand (because in code base instead of table).

Comment: it's part of 'select' @jarlh

Comment: @knut i'm fairly newish to CTE, i'll look that up, could be promising :)

Comment: If you can't persist the values in a table somewhere then maybe inline them as a `JOIN (VALUES ...)` instead. It won't be as performant as a persisted table, though.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by various commenters an extra table is beneficial. As this is not possible a useful alternative is a Common Table Expression (CTE).

Main advantage is that a CTE can be written on-the-fly and still be used like a table. In case as a table supplement a CTE should have no more than 100 lines. Fewer are better as the CTE construct will have no index.

Simplified structure code

```
-- CTE structure
WITH
  <name>
[
(
  <column name>
[, <column name>]
[...]
)
]
AS
(
  SELECT
    ...
[ FROM 
    ...
]
)
...
```

Microsofts documentation is available at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16.

Suggested pseudo code for this question:

```
WITH
  cteCase
( -- names defined for columns overwrite everything out of the SELECT
  -- allows defined interface for later joins / evaluations
  ES
, CP
, Val
)
AS
(
  -- first line in CTE nominates column names
  SELECT Cast( 'W' AS varchar(5) ) AS ES, Cast( 'S' AS varchar(5) ) AS CP, Cast( -0.75 AS numeric(5,2) ) AS Val
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Cast( 'W' AS varchar(5) ) AS ES, Cast( 'C' AS varchar(5) ) AS CP, Cast( -0.06 AS numeric(5,2) ) AS Val
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Cast( 'W' AS varchar(5) ) AS ES, Cast( 'S2' AS varchar(5) ) AS CP, Cast( -0.5 AS numeric(5,2) ) AS Val
-- < rest follows here >
)
SELECT
  ...
FROM
  my.tablename AS basedata
  INNER JOIN cteCase AS casedata
    ON  casedata.ES = basedata.ES
    AND casedata.CP = basedata.WP
;
```

The CTE part establishes the pseudo table and for brevity's sake I only included three lines out of the Case statement.

The established CTE can then be used like an ordinary table. Please note a CTE misses indexing and acts similar to a table variable in performance. It works similar to a subquery except for structural appearance.

Comment: And a warning note: Original poster mentioned many case options. A CTE can and will cause serious performance problems from a certain number of entries upwards!

Answer (score 0):

My answer based on your and the other comments on your question is to use a CTE to make it easier to manage the mapping. It's functional and tested code:

```
USE tempdb;

-- Create example data
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.tData;
CREATE TABLE dbo.tData 
(
    ID int NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1),
    ES varchar(1) NOT NULL,
    CP varchar(2) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_tData
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (ID)
);

INSERT INTO dbo.tData ( ES, CP)
VALUES
('W', 'S'), 
('W', 'C'), 
('W', 'S2'), 
('W', 'P'), 
('S', 'S'), 
('S', 'C'), 
('S', 'S2'), 
('S', 'F'),
('a', 'a'); -- Unmapped data;



-- Create mapping as common table expression CTE
;WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT * FROM (
    VALUES
    ('W', 'S',  -.75),
    ('W', 'C',  -.06),
    ('W', 'S2', -.5),
    ('W', 'P',  -.3),
    ('W', 'F',  -.1),
    ('S', 'S',  -.75),
    ('S', 'C',  -.08),
    ('S', 'S2', -.8),
    ('S', 'P',  -.2),
    ('S', 'F',  -.4)
    ) M (ES, CP, Outcome)
)
-- Use mapping
SELECT 
    D.ID,
    ISNULL(M.Outcome, 0) AS Outcome
FROM dbo.tData D
LEFT JOIN CTE M ON M.CP = D.CP AND M.ES = D.ES;


-- Cleanup
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.tData;
```

This is the result:

| ID | Outcome |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | -0.75 |
| 2 | -0.06 |
| 3 | -0.50 |
| 4 | -0.30 |
| 5 | -0.75 |
| 6 | -0.08 |
| 7 | -0.80 |
| 8 | -0.40 |
| 9 | 0.00 |

You can read about common table expression at [Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

*** Edit ***
I think that this code nor any other suggested solution except using an additional mapping table does make the code look much prettier.

So maybe you could just format your code more clean, like

```
CASE 
    WHEN ES = 'W' AND CP = 'S'  THEN -.75
    WHEN ES = 'W' AND CP = 'C'  THEN -.06
    WHEN ES = 'W' AND CP = 'S2' THEN -.5
    WHEN ES = 'W' AND CP = 'P'  THEN -.3
    WHEN ES = 'W' AND CP = 'F'  THEN -.1
    WHEN ES = 'S' AND CP = 'S'  THEN -.75
    WHEN ES = 'S' AND CP = 'C'  THEN -.08
    WHEN ES = 'S' AND CP = 'S2' THEN -.8
    WHEN ES = 'S' AND CP = 'P'  THEN -.2
    WHEN ES = 'S' AND CP = 'F'  THEN -.4
    ELSE 0
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot add it as a permanent table to your database, I'd actually suggest using a `VALUES` clause within your `FROM` to construct a table-like value to join to:

```
select
    ot.*, cv.Val as CaseValue
from
    (VALUES ('Something', 'SomethingElse', 'W','P')) ot (Column1, Column2, ES, CP)
        join
    (VALUES
        ('W','S',.75),
        ('W','C' ,-.06),
        ('W','S2', -.5),
        ('W','P' ,-.3),
        ('W','F' ,-.1),
        ('S','S' ,-.75),
        ('S','C' ,-.08),
        ('S','S2', -.8),
        ('S','P' ,-.2),
        ('S','F' ,-.4)
    ) cv (ES, CP, Val)
        on
            ot.ES = cv.ES and
            ot.CP = cv.CP
```

Here, I've named my first source `ot`, and it's meant to be whatever your original table/query is/was.

The second I've named `cv` and it's your "Case Values". As you can see, we can keep this quite compact and let us focus on the *data*, not some mechanism that's getting in the way.